# git: how to move committed changes from master to branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

We have a project where one of the developers made a few commits into the master branch -- instead of creating a separate branch off of master -- and broke things. How do I:

1. Undo those commits in master
2. Make a branch from master
3. Re-commit (or whatever the right git term for this is) those commits into the new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make 1 & 2, but you could simple take care about 2&3, and then make 1.

> 1. Make a branch from master
> 2. Re-commit (or whatever the right git term for this is) those commits into the new branch?

Assuming you have those bad commits on your `master` branch in your working copy:

Simply create and switch to new branch:

```
git checkout -b name_of_new_branch
```

and then push it to repo:

```
git push -u origin name_of_new_branch
```

your colleague now should be able to do:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout name_of_new_branch
```

---

> 1. Undo those commits in master

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

where `N` is number of bad commits of your colleague.

then, if you could override branches in your repo (default setting in github), then you could:

`git push origin master --force`

Please be very careful with this options. if I were in your shoes I will wait till someone confirm, that those commands are correct ;)